# Marshal with "const void * key, void * out" as parameter?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, marshalling

I need to call a c++ method via dllimport. Everything is working fine as long as there are not the following two parameters in the c++ method:

```
const void * key,
void * out
```

I think I need to marshal them. But how does it work?
The key should be a pointer to a byte array and the out parameter is also a byte array with a length of 16.

After trying what Jcl suggests, I have the following:

Using the first method (use out byte[] outprm), the program crashes without error (when reaching the call point).
But using the second way (from Jcl's comment), I have the following:

```
[DllImport(@"MyDLL.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void MyMethod(IntPtr key, out IntPtr outprm); 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        byte[] hash = new byte[16];
        byte[] myArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        IntPtr outprm = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(hash.Length);
        IntPtr key = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myArray.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(myArray, 0, key, myArray.Length);
        MyMethod(key, out outprm);
        Marshal.Copy(outprm, hash, 0, 16);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(key);                       
    }
```

Now there is no error when calling MyMethod. I just get the following error when I try to copy the data back: AccessViolationException

It said I want to write into protected memory. The dll and the c# software is x64 (and needs to be x64). Maybe this i the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IntPtr` for both key and out, something like:

```
[DllImport ("whatever.dll")]
public static extern void MyMethod(IntPtr key, IntPtr outprm);
```

To make `key` be an IntPtr, taking `myArray` being a byte array:

```
IntPtr key = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myArray.Length);
Marshal.Copy(myArray, 0, key, myArray.Length);
// ... call your function ...
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(key );
```

To get the 16 byte array from `outprm`:

```
IntPtr outprm;
MyMethod(key, outprm);
byte [] myArray = new byte[16];
Marshal.Copy(outprm, myArray, 0, 16);
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Now I call my method without problems. But I have problems to get the outprm. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I've changed the method so you do it with IntPtr... you can't actually Marshal a byte array automatically unless it's a string (with null terminator) in C++. You'll need to copy from the unmanaged IntPtr to a managed array afterwards (to specify the length). Keep in mind C++ arrays do not necessarily have a defined length... managed arrays do.

Comment: Thank you, it worked (need to remove the out before IntPtr outprm like you have) and I need to assign values to outprm: IntPtr outprm = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(16);
Then it works. Will I need to free the outprm space up when I am done?

Comment: Yes, if `outprm` is only allocated from within managed code, then you should use `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`... if it isn't, then you should have another unmanaged function to free it up